# Problems setting chaptermark in headings

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr

I am producing a small document, oneside. I'd like to have the following structure of headings/footers:

1. Document title in the **left side header**
2. Chapter name in the **right side header**
3. Page number in the **center footer**

I tried using the `fancyhdr` package, but the right header isn't printed (everything else works fine).

Here is a MWE, can you please help?

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% !TEX spellcheck = it-IT
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}                          
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}                                    
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}    
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}
\setmainfont{Bauer Bodoni Std 1}[
Ligatures={TeX},
Numbers=OldStyle,
SmallCapsFeatures={%
LetterSpace=4,
Letters=SmallCaps
}]
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\rm\filcenter}{\thesection}{0em}{}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]{}{\scshape\contentslabel{2.3em}}{}{\titlerule*[1pc]{}\contentspage}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\Large\scshape\filcenter}{}{0em}{}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\lhead{\scshape Title}\rhead{\chaptermark}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}
\chead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum{10}
\end{document}
```

Can someone show me what I've done wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you use `titlesec` and `titletoc`, I wanted to point it is much simpler to use the `pagestyles` option of `titlesec` to customise headers and footers. It works with `\chaptertitle`, `\sectiontitle` and the like, instead of playing with `marks` — although you still can use them.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a5paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}
\setmainfont{Bauer Bodoni Std 1}[
Ligatures={TeX},
Numbers=OldStyle,
SmallCapsFeatures={%
LetterSpace=4,
Letters=SmallCaps
}]
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\rm\filcenter}{\thesection}{0em}{}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]{}{\scshape\contentslabel{2.3em}}{}{\titlerule*[1pc]{}\contentspage}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\Large\scshape\filcenter}{}{0em}{}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{%
\sethead{Document Title}{}{\scshape\chaptertitle}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
\headrule
}

\begin{document}%

\pagestyle{mystyle}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum{10}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`\chaptermark` is a command to *store* an information (similar to e.g. `\label`), it is executed internally by `\chapter`. To *retrieve* the information use `\leftmark`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\rm\filcenter}{\thesection}{0em}{}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]{}{\scshape\contentslabel{2.3em}}{}{\titlerule*[1pc]{}\contentspage}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\Large\scshape\filcenter}{}{0em}{}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\lhead{\scshape Title}\rhead{\leftmark}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}
\chead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum{10}
\end{document}
```

(I removed fontspec and your local font as I don't have the font).

Comment: Yes thanks it works! I had to fiddle with the redefinition of `chaptermark` but it is all documented in the `fancyhdr` documentation